# Regulagem de svg

Tags: html, css, svg

Estou procurando novos efeitos, para melhorar meu portfólio.
Gostei muito desse efeito, mas tem um erro que não consegui ajustar.
A altura corta quando faz o hover.

Depois de muito procurar, consegui fazer um ajuste de tamanho, mexendo no parâmetro do svg:

`<polygon id="cp_poly_up" points="0,0 560,0 310,160" />` (Mudei para 560).

Mas agora precisaria ajustar a altura.

Há alguma documentação, ou os significados nos parâmetros, ou alguma ideia se estou no caminho certo?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,700,900|Dosis:800|Playfair+Display:400,400italic,900italic|Lora:700|Syncopate:700|Roboto+Condensed:300italic|Oswald:700);

@font-face {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-family: 'codropsicons';
 src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot');
 src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.svg#codropsicons') format('svg');
}

*, *:after, *:before { box-sizing: border-box; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {display: table;  content: ''; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

body {
 background: #fff;
 color: #1e1a1b;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
 outline: none;
 color: #dd3e62;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

 a:focus {
  outline: none;
 }

.hidden {
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}

/* Header */
.codrops-header {
 padding: 2em 1em 4em;
 text-align: center;
 height: calc(100vh - 40px);
 margin: 20px 20px 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
 flex-direction: column;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background: url(../img/mouse.svg) no-repeat left 50% bottom 40px;
}

.codrops-header::before,
.codrops-header::after {
 content: 'Lorizzleipsizzledolorcrazy amizzlefoshizzleizzleelit Nullizzlesapienvelizzle aliquetvolutpatfoshizzlefo shizzlemynizzlegravidafoshizzle Lorizzleipsizzledolorcrazy amizzlefoshizzleizzleelit Nullizzlesapienvelizzle aliquetvolutpatfoshizzlefo shizzlemynizzlegravidafoshizzle';
 font-size: 13em;
 line-height: 0.5;
 letter-spacing: -15px;
 z-index: 10;
 text-align: justify;
 pointer-events: none;
 position: absolute;
 background: #cdced2;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', cursive;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-style: italic;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 120%;
 height: 120%;
 top: -10%;
 left: -10%;
}

.codrops-header h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 1em;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 2.75em;
 line-height: 1;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 color: #49484a;
}

.codrops-header h1 span {
 font-style: italic;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.codrops-header h1 .sub {
 display: block;
 padding: 0.75em 0;
 color: #F9F9F9;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 68%;
 text-transform: none;
}

/* Top Navigation Style */
.codrops-links {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-flex: none;
 flex: none;
}

.codrops-links::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 width: 1px;
 height: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,22.5deg);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,22.5deg);
}

.codrops-icon {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.codrops-icon span {
 display: none;
}

.codrops-icon:before {
 margin: 0 5px;
 text-transform: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-family: 'codropsicons';
 line-height: 1;

 speak: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.codrops-icon--drop:before {
 content: "\e001";
}

.codrops-icon--prev:before {
 content: "\e004";
}

/* Grid */
.grid__item {
 height: calc(100vh - 40px);
 min-height: 460px;
 max-width: calc(100vw - 40px);
 background: #DDD;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 100px 0;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
 justify-content: center;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Solves Safari bug because of SVG clipping mask */
}

.grid__item p {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #777;
}

/* Background colors */
.color-1 { background: #E8E0DA; }
.color-2 { background: #576b67; }
.color-3 { background: #383A35; }
.color-4 { background: #333; }
.color-5 { background: #fda9a9; }
.color-7 { background: #cde7d3; }
.color-8 { background: #DCECDD; }
.color-9 { background: #dedbba; }
.color-10 { background: #222; }
.color-11 { background: #515151; }

/* Related demos */
.content--related {
 padding: 3em 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.media-item {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 1em;
 vertical-align: top;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.media-item__img {
 max-width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.3;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.media-item:hover .media-item__img,
.media-item:focus .media-item__img {
 opacity: 1;
}

.media-item__title {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.5em;
 font-size: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
 .codrops-header {
  padding: 3em 10% 4em;
 }
 .grid__item {
  width: 100%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
 .codrops-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.85em;
 }
}


/* General link styles */
.link {
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 8em;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #9e9ba4;
 display: inline-block;
}

/* Kukuri */
.link--kukuri {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 900;
 overflow: hidden;
 line-height: 0.75;
 color: #c5c2b8;
}

.link--kukuri:hover {
 color: #c5c2b8;
}

.link--kukuri::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 16px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -8px;
 right: 0;
 background: #F9F9F9;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.link--kukuri:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.link--kukuri::before {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #424242;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
 transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
}

.link--kukuri:hover::before {
 width: 100%;
}

/* Takiri */
.link--takiri {
 font-style: italic;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 7em;
 padding: 0 10px 20px;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s;
}

.link--takiri:hover {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--takiri::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 36px;
 width: 120%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -18px;
 left: -10%;
 z-index: -1;
 background: #F9F9F9;
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) scale3d(0,1,1);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--takiri:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.link--takiri span {
 font-size: 20%;
 font-weight: 400;
 position: absolute;
 right: 15px;
 color: #e53369;
 bottom: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,-10px,0);
 transform: translate3d(-10px,-10px,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}

.link--takiri:hover span {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/* Surinami */
.link--surinami {
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9em;
 color: #3A4945;
 padding: 0 0 0.125em;
}

.link--surinami::before,
.link--surinami::after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 3px;
 z-index: -1;
 background: #3A4945;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--surinami::before {
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
 transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.link--surinami::after {
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
 transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.link--surinami:hover::before,
.link--surinami:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.link--surinami span {
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s;
}

.link--surinami:hover span {
 color: transparent;
}

.link--surinami span::before,
.link--surinami span::after {
 position: absolute;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}

.link--surinami span::before {
 content: attr(data-letters-l);
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5px,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-5px,0,0);
}

.link--surinami span::after {
 content: attr(data-letters-r);
 right: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(5px,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(5px,0,0);
}

.link--surinami:hover span::before,
.link--surinami:hover span::after {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/* Nukun */
.link--nukun {
 color: #E3E8DC;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px 0;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.link--nukun:hover {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--nukun::before,
.link--nukun::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 30%;
 height: 5px;
 background: #E3E8DC;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 35%;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
}

.link--nukun::after {
 background: #ACD07A;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0) scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0) scale3d(0,1,1);
}

.link--nukun:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(300%,0,0) scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: translate3d(300%,0,0) scale3d(0,1,1);
}

.link--nukun:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.link--nukun span {
 color: #E3E8DC;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, color 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s, color 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
}

.link--nukun:hover span {
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}

/* Kumya */
.link--kumya {
 font-family: 'Syncopate', sans-serif;
 font-size: 6.5em;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px 10px 0;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #242424;
}

.link--kumya:hover {
 color: #242424;
}

.link--kumya::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 background: #242424;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(101%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(101%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.link--kumya:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.link--kumya span {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}

.link--kumya span::before {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 position: absolute;
 color: #fff;
 left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
 transition: width 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.link--kumya:hover span::before {
 width: 100%;
}

/* Urpi */
.link--urpi {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-size: 10em;
 /* font-weight: 700; */
 /* text-transform: uppercase; */
 color: #e78383;
 -webkit-transition: color 0s 0.5s;
 transition: color 0s 0.5s;
}

.link--urpi:hover {
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}

.link--urpi::before,
.link--urpi::after {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 color: #e78383;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.link--urpi::before {
 -webkit-clip-path: url(#cp_up); 
 clip-path: url(../index.html#cp_up);
}

.link--urpi::after {
 -webkit-clip-path: url(#cp_down); 
 clip-path: url(../index.html#cp_down);
}

.link--urpi:hover::before,
.link--urpi:hover::after {
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.link--urpi:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(4px,1px,0);
 transform: translate3d(4px,1px,0);
}

.link--urpi:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-4px,-1px,0);
 transform: translate3d(-4px,-1px,0);
}

/* Mallki */
.link--mallki {
 font-weight: 800;
 color: #81a689;
 font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s 0.25s;
 transition: color 0.5s 0.25s;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.link--mallki:hover {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 transition: none;
 color: transparent;
}

.link--mallki::before {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 6px;
 margin: -3px 0 0 0;
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.link--mallki:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.link--mallki span {
 position: absolute;
 height: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.link--mallki span::before {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 color: red;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--mallki span:nth-child(2) {
 top: 50%;
}

.link--mallki span:first-child::before {
 top: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

.link--mallki span:nth-child(2)::before {
 bottom: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

.link--mallki:hover span::before {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
}

/* Manko */
.link--manko {
 color: #B1C0B2;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-style: italic;
 padding: 0.65em 0 0.8em;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s;
}

.link--manko:hover {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--manko::before,
.link--manko::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 border-width: 4px 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #fff;
 pointer-events: none;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
}

.link--manko::before {
 width: 50%;
 left: 25%;
 height: 80%;
 top: 10%;
}

.link--manko::after {
 width: 30%;
 left: 35%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
}

.link--manko:hover::before,
.link--manko:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.link--manko span {
 color: #60AB64;
 font-weight: 400;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 0.2em;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.link--manko span:first-of-type {
 bottom: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8,0.8,1) translate3d(0,10px,0);
 transform: scale3d(0.8,0.8,1) translate3d(0,10px,0);
}

.link--manko span:last-of-type {
 top: 100%;
 margin-top: 10px;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8,0.8,1) translate3d(0,-10px,0);
 transform: scale3d(0.8,0.8,1) translate3d(0,-10px,0);
}

.link--manko:hover span {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.link--manko:hover span:first-of-type {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
 transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.link--manko:hover span:last-of-type {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.20s;
 transition-delay: 0.20s;
}

/* Ilin */
.link--ilin {
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 0.8;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #adaa88;
}

.link--ilin span { 
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s;
}

.link--ilin:hover span:first-of-type {
 color: #fff;
}

.link--ilin:hover span:last-of-type {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--ilin span::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 line-height: 0.8;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--ilin span:last-of-type::before {
 background: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--ilin:hover span:last-of-type::before,
.link--ilin span:first-of-type::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-150%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-150%,0);
}

.link--ilin:hover span:first-of-type::before,
.link--ilin span:last-of-type::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,150%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,150%,0);
}

/* Asiri */
.link--asiri {
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
}

.link--asiri .text-fill {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.link--asiri canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.link--asiri .svg-inverted-mask {
 position: absolute;
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #222; /* FF rendering issue */
}

.link--asiri .shape--fill {
 fill: #222;
}

.link--asiri .text--transparent {
 fill: #95D384;
 -webkit-transition: fill 0.2s;
 transition: fill 0.2s;
}

.link--asiri:hover .text--transparent {
 fill: transparent;
}

.svg--asiri .mask__shape {
 fill: white;
}

.text--asiri {
 font-size: 150px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 900;
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1.5;
}

/* Yaku */
.link--yaku {
 color: #D3D3D3;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display';
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 10em;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 10px;
}

.link--yaku::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 border-width: 2px 0;
 border-color: #282828;
 border-style: solid;
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-101%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-101%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--yaku:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.link--yaku span {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, color 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

.link--yaku:hover span {
 color: #1e1a1b;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
}

.link--yaku span:nth-child(4),
.link--yaku:hover span:first-child {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}

.link--yaku span:nth-child(3),
.link--yaku:hover span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
 transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.link--yaku span:nth-child(2),
.link--yaku:hover span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.link--yaku span:first-child,
.link--yaku:hover span:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
 .link--surinami { font-size: 3em; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 42em) {
 .link--takiri { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--kukuri { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--nukun { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--kumya { font-size: 3em; }
 .link--manko { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--urpi { font-size: 5em; }
 .link--mallki { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--ilin { font-size: 5em; }
 .link--asiri { -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.65,0.65,1); transform: scale3d(0.65,0.65,1); }
 .link--yaku { font-size: 4em; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Inspiration for Text Styles and Hover Effects</title>
 <meta name="description" content="A set of modern text styles and hover effects for your inspiration" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="text style, link style, link hover, effect, animation, inspiration, web design" />
 <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />

 <!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 <style> /* Firefox seems to have issues loading the clip path from inside the CSS */
  .link--urpi::before {
   -webkit-clip-path: url(#cp_up); 
   clip-path: url(#cp_up);
  }

  .link--urpi::after {
   -webkit-clip-path: url(#cp_down); 
   clip-path: url(#cp_down);
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- clipping mask for style "Urpi" -->
 <svg class="hidden" viewBox="0 0 310 160">
  <defs>
   <clippath id="cp_up">
    <polygon id="cp_poly_up" points="0,0 310,0 310,160" />
   </clippath>
   <clippath id="cp_down">
    <polygon id="cp_poly_down" points="0,0 0,160 310,160" />
   </clippath>
  </defs>
 </svg>


   

   <div class="grid__item color-5">
    <a class="link link--urpi" href="#" data-letters="Urpi">Urpi</a>
   </div>


 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cara eu tinha dado uma resposta, mas depois preferi edita-la, já que o problema se resolvia apenas tirando o `overflow:hidden` do lugar errado, e não colocando  `overflow:hidden` em mais um elemento... Seu problema na verdade nem é propriamente com o SVG pelo que vi....

Answer (score 1):

Reformulando a resposta, seu problema é mais simples do que vc pensa. Vc simplesmente colocou um `overflow:hidden` nos pseudo-elementos `.link--urpi::before` e `.link--urpi::after` com isso uma parte deles estava ficando cortada, dando a impressão desse pequeno Bug que na verdade não é no SVG e sim no CSS

Eu apenas removi esse `overflow:hidden` dessas classes e ficou tudo certinho

Veja como fica o resultado.

```css
.link--urpi::before {
   -webkit-clip-path: url(#cp_up); 
   clip-path: url(#cp_up);
  }

  .link--urpi::after {
   -webkit-clip-path: url(#cp_down); 
   clip-path: url(#cp_down);
  }


        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,700,900|Dosis:800|Playfair+Display:400,400italic,900italic|Lora:700|Syncopate:700|Roboto+Condensed:300italic|Oswald:700);

@font-face {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-family: 'codropsicons';
 src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot');
 src:url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/codropsicons/codropsicons.svg#codropsicons') format('svg');
}

*, *:after, *:before { box-sizing: border-box; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {display: table;  content: ''; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

body {
 background: #fff;
 color: #1e1a1b;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
 outline: none;
 color: #dd3e62;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

 a:focus {
  outline: none;
 }

.hidden {
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}

/* Header */
.codrops-header {
 padding: 2em 1em 4em;
 text-align: center;
 height: calc(100vh - 40px);
 margin: 20px 20px 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
 flex-direction: column;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background: url(../img/mouse.svg) no-repeat left 50% bottom 40px;
}

.codrops-header::before,
.codrops-header::after {
 content: 'Lorizzleipsizzledolorcrazy amizzlefoshizzleizzleelit Nullizzlesapienvelizzle aliquetvolutpatfoshizzlefo shizzlemynizzlegravidafoshizzle Lorizzleipsizzledolorcrazy amizzlefoshizzleizzleelit Nullizzlesapienvelizzle aliquetvolutpatfoshizzlefo shizzlemynizzlegravidafoshizzle';
 font-size: 13em;
 line-height: 0.5;
 letter-spacing: -15px;
 z-index: 10;
 text-align: justify;
 pointer-events: none;
 position: absolute;
 background: #cdced2;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', cursive;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-style: italic;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 120%;
 height: 120%;
 top: -10%;
 left: -10%;
}

.codrops-header h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 1em;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size: 2.75em;
 line-height: 1;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 color: #49484a;
}

.codrops-header h1 span {
 font-style: italic;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.codrops-header h1 .sub {
 display: block;
 padding: 0.75em 0;
 color: #F9F9F9;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 68%;
 text-transform: none;
}

/* Top Navigation Style */
.codrops-links {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-flex: none;
 flex: none;
}

.codrops-links::after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 width: 1px;
 height: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,22.5deg);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,22.5deg);
}

.codrops-icon {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.codrops-icon span {
 display: none;
}

.codrops-icon:before {
 margin: 0 5px;
 text-transform: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-family: 'codropsicons';
 line-height: 1;

 speak: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.codrops-icon--drop:before {
 content: "\e001";
}

.codrops-icon--prev:before {
 content: "\e004";
}

/* Grid */
.grid__item {
 height: calc(100vh - 40px);
 min-height: 460px;
 max-width: calc(100vw - 40px);
 background: #DDD;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 100px 0;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 -webkit-justify-content: center;
 justify-content: center;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Solves Safari bug because of SVG clipping mask */
}

.grid__item p {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #777;
}

/* Background colors */
.color-1 { background: #E8E0DA; }
.color-2 { background: #576b67; }
.color-3 { background: #383A35; }
.color-4 { background: #333; }
.color-5 { background: #fda9a9; }
.color-7 { background: #cde7d3; }
.color-8 { background: #DCECDD; }
.color-9 { background: #dedbba; }
.color-10 { background: #222; }
.color-11 { background: #515151; }

/* Related demos */
.content--related {
 padding: 3em 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.media-item {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 1em;
 vertical-align: top;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.media-item__img {
 max-width: 100%;
 opacity: 0.3;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.media-item:hover .media-item__img,
.media-item:focus .media-item__img {
 opacity: 1;
}

.media-item__title {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.5em;
 font-size: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
 .codrops-header {
  padding: 3em 10% 4em;
 }
 .grid__item {
  width: 100%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
 .codrops-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.85em;
 }
}


/* General link styles */
.link {
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 8em;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #9e9ba4;
 display: inline-block;
}

/* Kukuri */
.link--kukuri {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 900;
 overflow: hidden;
 line-height: 0.75;
 color: #c5c2b8;
}

.link--kukuri:hover {
 color: #c5c2b8;
}

.link--kukuri::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 16px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -8px;
 right: 0;
 background: #F9F9F9;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.link--kukuri:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.link--kukuri::before {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #424242;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
 transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
}

.link--kukuri:hover::before {
 width: 100%;
}

/* Takiri */
.link--takiri {
 font-style: italic;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 7em;
 padding: 0 10px 20px;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s;
}

.link--takiri:hover {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--takiri::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 36px;
 width: 120%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -18px;
 left: -10%;
 z-index: -1;
 background: #F9F9F9;
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) scale3d(0,1,1);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--takiri:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,45deg) scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.link--takiri span {
 font-size: 20%;
 font-weight: 400;
 position: absolute;
 right: 15px;
 color: #e53369;
 bottom: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,-10px,0);
 transform: translate3d(-10px,-10px,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}

.link--takiri:hover span {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/* Surinami */
.link--surinami {
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9em;
 color: #3A4945;
 padding: 0 0 0.125em;
}

.link--surinami::before,
.link--surinami::after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 3px;
 z-index: -1;
 background: #3A4945;
 position: absolute;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--surinami::before {
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
 transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.link--surinami::after {
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
 transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.link--surinami:hover::before,
.link--surinami:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.link--surinami span {
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s;
}

.link--surinami:hover span {
 color: transparent;
}

.link--surinami span::before,
.link--surinami span::after {
 position: absolute;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}

.link--surinami span::before {
 content: attr(data-letters-l);
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5px,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-5px,0,0);
}

.link--surinami span::after {
 content: attr(data-letters-r);
 right: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(5px,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(5px,0,0);
}

.link--surinami:hover span::before,
.link--surinami:hover span::after {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/* Nukun */
.link--nukun {
 color: #E3E8DC;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px 0;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.link--nukun:hover {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--nukun::before,
.link--nukun::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 30%;
 height: 5px;
 background: #E3E8DC;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 35%;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
}

.link--nukun::after {
 background: #ACD07A;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0) scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: translate3d(-300%,0,0) scale3d(0,1,1);
}

.link--nukun:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(300%,0,0) scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: translate3d(300%,0,0) scale3d(0,1,1);
}

.link--nukun:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0) scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.link--nukun span {
 color: #E3E8DC;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, color 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s, color 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
}

.link--nukun:hover span {
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
}

/* Kumya */
.link--kumya {
 font-family: 'Syncopate', sans-serif;
 font-size: 6.5em;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 10px 10px 0;
 line-height: 1;
 color: #242424;
}

.link--kumya:hover {
 color: #242424;
}

.link--kumya::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 background: #242424;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(101%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(101%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.link--kumya:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.link--kumya span {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
}

.link--kumya span::before {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 position: absolute;
 color: #fff;
 left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 0%;
 -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
 transition: width 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.link--kumya:hover span::before {
 width: 100%;
}

/* Urpi */
.link--urpi {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-size: 10em;
 /* font-weight: 700; */
 /* text-transform: uppercase; */
 color: #e78383;
 -webkit-transition: color 0s 0.5s;
 transition: color 0s 0.5s;
}

.link--urpi:hover {
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-transition: none;
 transition: none;
}

.link--urpi::before,
.link--urpi::after {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 color: #e78383;
 /* overflow: hidden; */
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.link--urpi::before {
 -webkit-clip-path: url(#cp_up); 
 clip-path: url(../index.html#cp_up);
}

.link--urpi::after {
 -webkit-clip-path: url(#cp_down); 
 clip-path: url(../index.html#cp_down);
}

.link--urpi:hover::before,
.link--urpi:hover::after {
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.link--urpi:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(4px,1px,0);
 transform: translate3d(4px,1px,0);
}

.link--urpi:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-4px,-1px,0);
 transform: translate3d(-4px,-1px,0);
}

/* Mallki */
.link--mallki {
 font-weight: 800;
 color: #81a689;
 font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s 0.25s;
 transition: color 0.5s 0.25s;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.link--mallki:hover {
 -webkit-transition: none;
 transition: none;
 color: transparent;
}

.link--mallki::before {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 6px;
 margin: -3px 0 0 0;
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
}

.link--mallki:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.link--mallki span {
 position: absolute;
 height: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.link--mallki span::before {
 content: attr(data-letters);
 color: red;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--mallki span:nth-child(2) {
 top: 50%;
}

.link--mallki span:first-child::before {
 top: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

.link--mallki span:nth-child(2)::before {
 bottom: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

.link--mallki:hover span::before {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
}

/* Manko */
.link--manko {
 color: #B1C0B2;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-style: italic;
 padding: 0.65em 0 0.8em;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s;
}

.link--manko:hover {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--manko::before,
.link--manko::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 border-width: 4px 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #fff;
 pointer-events: none;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
 transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2,1,0.3,1);
}

.link--manko::before {
 width: 50%;
 left: 25%;
 height: 80%;
 top: 10%;
}

.link--manko::after {
 width: 30%;
 left: 35%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
}

.link--manko:hover::before,
.link--manko:hover::after {
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
 transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.link--manko span {
 color: #60AB64;
 font-weight: 400;
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 0.2em;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.link--manko span:first-of-type {
 bottom: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8,0.8,1) translate3d(0,10px,0);
 transform: scale3d(0.8,0.8,1) translate3d(0,10px,0);
}

.link--manko span:last-of-type {
 top: 100%;
 margin-top: 10px;
 -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8,0.8,1) translate3d(0,-10px,0);
 transform: scale3d(0.8,0.8,1) translate3d(0,-10px,0);
}

.link--manko:hover span {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.link--manko:hover span:first-of-type {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
 transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.link--manko:hover span:last-of-type {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.20s;
 transition-delay: 0.20s;
}

/* Ilin */
.link--ilin {
 font-weight: 900;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 line-height: 0.8;
 overflow: hidden;
 color: #adaa88;
}

.link--ilin span { 
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.5s;
 transition: color 0.5s;
}

.link--ilin:hover span:first-of-type {
 color: #fff;
}

.link--ilin:hover span:last-of-type {
 color: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--ilin span::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 line-height: 0.8;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--ilin span:last-of-type::before {
 background: #1e1a1b;
}

.link--ilin:hover span:last-of-type::before,
.link--ilin span:first-of-type::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-150%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,-150%,0);
}

.link--ilin:hover span:first-of-type::before,
.link--ilin span:last-of-type::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,150%,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,150%,0);
}

/* Asiri */
.link--asiri {
 position: relative;
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
}

.link--asiri .text-fill {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.link--asiri canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.link--asiri .svg-inverted-mask {
 position: absolute;
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #222; /* FF rendering issue */
}

.link--asiri .shape--fill {
 fill: #222;
}

.link--asiri .text--transparent {
 fill: #95D384;
 -webkit-transition: fill 0.2s;
 transition: fill 0.2s;
}

.link--asiri:hover .text--transparent {
 fill: transparent;
}

.svg--asiri .mask__shape {
 fill: white;
}

.text--asiri {
 font-size: 150px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 900;
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1.5;
}

/* Yaku */
.link--yaku {
 color: #D3D3D3;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display';
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 10em;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 10px;
}

.link--yaku::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 border-width: 2px 0;
 border-color: #282828;
 border-style: solid;
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-101%,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(-101%,0,0);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.link--yaku:hover::before {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.link--yaku span {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, color 0.5s;
 transition: transform 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

.link--yaku:hover span {
 color: #1e1a1b;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0,1,0,360deg);
}

.link--yaku span:nth-child(4),
.link--yaku:hover span:first-child {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-delay: 0s;
}

.link--yaku span:nth-child(3),
.link--yaku:hover span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
 transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.link--yaku span:nth-child(2),
.link--yaku:hover span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
 transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.link--yaku span:first-child,
.link--yaku:hover span:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
 transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
 .link--surinami { font-size: 3em; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 42em) {
 .link--takiri { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--kukuri { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--nukun { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--kumya { font-size: 3em; }
 .link--manko { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--urpi { font-size: 5em; }
 .link--mallki { font-size: 3.5em; }
 .link--ilin { font-size: 5em; }
 .link--asiri { -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.65,0.65,1); transform: scale3d(0.65,0.65,1); }
 .link--yaku { font-size: 4em; }
}
```

```html
<svg class="hidden" viewBox="0 0 310 160">
    <defs>
        <clippath id="cp_up">
            <polygon id="cp_poly_up" points="0,0 310,0 310,160" />
        </clippath>
        <clippath id="cp_down">
            <polygon id="cp_poly_down" points="0,0 0,160 310,160" />
        </clippath>
    </defs>
</svg>

<div class="grid__item color-5">
    <a class="link link--urpi" href="#" data-letters="Urpi">Urpi</a>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Estou achando que tem MUITO css para pouca coisa, e ainda SVG. Acredito que apenas com CSS vc chegaria nesse efeito. Outra coisa, *agora é uma observação particular*, por favor nós estamos em uma comunidade pensando em ajudar o próximo ok, um conselho que vou te dar é ainda não colocar esse efeito no seu portfólio, pelo menos não até vc domina-lo completamente... No mais boa sorte ai!

Comment: Entendi.Desculpe pela postagem da dúvida e obrigado. Vou ter mais ponderação na próxima vez.

Comment: @RogérioPancini não é um puxão de orelha não rss. É só uma dia! Eu achei que tem muitas linhas de css ai.... Talvez de para vc dar uma limpada nesse código. Vai até melhorar pra vc mesmo dar manutenção nisso depois. E o lance de Incluir no seu portfólio é pq se o seu chefe te pedir pra fazer uma alteração no formato ou algo do tipo e vc não dominar a técnica vc vai ficar enrascado entende. São só dicas. Depois da uma olhada em animações feitas com `@keyframes`, da pra fazer muita coisa legal e de forma mais prática!